# How to find patterns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using `pandas` and `python`, I want to find a pattern where a stream's inflow is much larger than usual, and it is followed within 5 days with an outflow that is no less than 5% of the inflow in the stream. See data frame below.

I want to be able to flag this movement in a new column (let's call it flag).

Imagine this data frame has thousands of rows and you want to find a similar pattern and have it flagged throughout.

```
Index    date           stream
0        2019-01-01        2
1        2019-01-02        0
2        2019-01-03        1
3        2019-01-04        0
4        2019-01-05        3
5        2019-01-06        2
7        2019-01-07        100
8        2019-01-08        0
9        2019-01-09        0
10       2019-01-10       -95
11       2019-01-11        3    
12       2019-01-13        0  
13       2019-01-14        2
14       2019-01-15       -1
15       2019-01-16        0
16       2019-01-17        2
17       2019-01-18        93
18       2019-01-19       -2
19       2019-01-20       -89
```

Comment: Define "_much larger than usual_".

Comment: I'm thinking at least more than 20X the previous 5 day average. So we have a 2, a 0, a 1, a 0 and suddenly a 100, which is definitely more than 20x that average over those previous days

Comment: You don't have any of them in your example. Please add. You have only four days before the first burst.

Comment: okay. i just added, but not looking as well formatted as first 12 rows.

Comment: You can calculate the 5 days moving average and eventually filter out with Bollinger bands.

Comment: hmm. would i get the moving average like this: `df['Date'].rolling(window=5).mean()`

How would i place that into a new column? sorry, i am a newbie at both stackoverflow and pandas/python...but trying hard to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a `rolling averaging` on `df['stream']`.

```
stream = [2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 100, 0, 0, -95, 3, 0, 2, -1, 0, 2, 93, -2, -89]
date = [
    '2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05',
    '2019-01-06', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-10',
    '2019-01-11', '2019-01-13', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-15', '2019-01-16',
    '2019-01-17', '2019-01-18', '2019-01-19', '2019-01-20'
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'stream': stream})

def process(row):
    if row['stream'] > 20*row['stream_mean']:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
df['stream_mean'] = df['stream'].rolling(5).mean()
df['stream_mean'] = df['stream_mean'].shift(periods=1)
df['flag'] = df.apply(process,axis=1)
df
```

It would be better if you apply `Bollinger Band` and create a `Standard Deviation column` and may be also try a `95% Confidence interval` method.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That worked beautifully, Kartikey. Thanks so much. Now to figure out Bollinger Bands.

Comment: Thank you :) For `Bollinger Bands` Create a function to filter out values for 95% confidence interval try ` (x_mean - 1.96*x_standard_deviation, x_mean + 1.96*x_standard_deviation)`