# Flag if row meets criteria within n days

Tags: python, pandas

[In a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937101/how-to-find-patterns-in-pandas), @KartikeySingh, got me very close. But I need to refine it further by flagging only the positive inflow when at least 90% of it flows out  (negative flow) within a 5 day period. So in the example below, index 4 and 5 should not get flagged, but index items 7, 10, 17 and 19 should get flagged because the inflows and outflows meet those parameters. So how would I flag only the inflow and outflows that are within 90% (negative value) of each other and the outflow occurs within 5 days of the inflow.

```
stream = [2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 100, 0, 0, -95, 3, 0, 2, -1, 0, 2, 93, -2, -89]
date = [
'2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05',
'2019-01-06', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-10',
'2019-01-11', '2019-01-13', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-15', '2019-01-16',
'2019-01-17', '2019-01-18', '2019-01-19', '2019-01-20'
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'stream': stream})

def process(row):
if row['stream'] > 20*row['stream_mean']:
    return 1
else:
    return 0
df['stream_mean'] = df['stream'].rolling(5).mean()
df['stream_mean'] = df['stream_mean'].shift(periods=1)
df['flag'] = df.apply(process,axis=1)
df
```

The code above flags all incoming flows regardless of the outflow criteria.

Comment: It would be helpful to link to the question you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is easier with `.loc`, you can use the following code,comments in the code are explaining the logic:

This part is just copy of your code from the question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
stream = [2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 100, 0, 0, -95, 3, 0, 2, -1, 0, 2, 93, -2, -89]
date = [
'2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05',
'2019-01-06', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-08', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-10',
'2019-01-11', '2019-01-13', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-15', '2019-01-16',
'2019-01-17', '2019-01-18', '2019-01-19', '2019-01-20'
]
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'stream': stream})
```

This is the code that solves the problem:

```
p_list=[n for n in df.stream if n >0] # we are getting positive values from stream column
p_mean=sum(p_list)/len(p_list) # finding mean (as unusual value threshold) 
n_list=[n for n in df.stream if n <0] #similarly getting negative values
n_mean=sum(n_list)/len(n_list) #finding threshold on the negative side.
```

After getting the threshold values(do see that you can manually set these values if you like this is just an attempt at automating the entire process).

```
p_flags=df.index[(df.stream > p_mean) &((df.stream.shift(-1) <=-.9*df.stream ) | (df.stream.shift(-2)<=-0.9*df.stream
                                                                      )|(df.stream.shift(-3)<=-0.9*df.stream
                                                                        )|(df.stream.shift(-4)<=-0.9*df.stream
                                                                          )|(df.stream.shift(-5)<=-0.9*df.stream
                                                                            ))]
```

what this will do is return the index of the rows with matching criteria, the logic of the criteria is very simply that we are checking if a row is greater than the p_mean value, if it is then we check if any of the next five rows have value that is less than 90% of such a value (that is outflow) `|` operator means or so any outflow in the next 5 will mean the part returns true.

in order to find the negative flags index we have a similar thing only in revers:

```
n_flags=df.index[(df.stream < n_mean) &((df.stream.shift(1) >=0.9*df.stream ) | (df.stream.shift(2)>=0.9*df.stream
                                                                  )|(df.stream.shift(3)>=0.9*df.stream
                                                                    )|(df.stream.shift(4)>=0.9*df.stream
                                                                      )|(df.stream.shift(5)>=0.9*df.stream
                                                                        ))]
```

Now you have the indices if the rows that matches the criteria in order to add this as a column in the dataframe simply do a:

```
flags=np.zeros(len(df))
for i1,i2 in zip(n_flags,p_flags):
    flags[i1]=1
    flags[i2]=1

df["flags"]=flags  
print(df)
```

The output will be:

```
    date    stream  flags
0   2019-01-01  2   0.0
1   2019-01-02  0   0.0
2   2019-01-03  1   0.0
3   2019-01-04  0   0.0
4   2019-01-05  3   0.0
5   2019-01-06  2   0.0
6   2019-01-07  100 1.0
7   2019-01-08  0   0.0
8   2019-01-09  0   0.0
9   2019-01-10  -95 1.0
10  2019-01-11  3   0.0
11  2019-01-13  0   0.0
12  2019-01-14  2   0.0
13  2019-01-15  -1  0.0
14  2019-01-16  0   0.0
15  2019-01-17  2   0.0
16  2019-01-18  93  1.0
17  2019-01-19  -2  0.0
18  2019-01-20  -89 1.0
```

Comment: Inder, this works beautifully in this dataframe. But i am getting a `'numpy.float64' object is not callable` for `p_mean=sum(p_list)/len(p_list)` and `n_mean=sum(n_list)/len(n_list)` when i run on my full dataset.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-27ed7ff8ac23> in <module>
      1 p_list=[n for n in etf.flow if n >0] # we are getting positive values from stream column
----> 2 p_mean=sum(p_list)/len(p_list) # finding mean (as unusual value threshold)
      3 n_list=[n for n in etf.flow if n <0] #similarly getting negative values
      4 n_mean=sum(n_list)/len(n_list) #finding threshold on the negative side.

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Comment: @SMJune put a line above p_list as::: `etf.stream=pd.to_numeric(etf.stream)`

Comment: so literally just add `etf.stream=pd.to_numeric(etf.stream)` above the p_list line?

Comment: pandas is evaluating that column as a `dtype('float64')`

Comment: yes, my actual data that stream column is actually called flow. so i changed all the instances. and that column is `dtype('float64')` as well. the error is:

Comment: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-8722e99d25e3> in <module>
      1 etf.flow = pd.to_numeric(etf.flow)
      2 p_list=[n for n in etf.flow if n >0] # we are getting positive values from stream column
----> 3 p_mean=sum(p_list)/len(p_list) # finding mean (as unusual value threshold)
      4 n_list=[n for n in etf.flow if n <0] #similarly getting negative values
      5 n_mean=sum(n_list)/len(n_list) #finding threshold on the negative side.

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189336/discussion-between-inder-and-smjune).